# Preimage proof question

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$. Suppose $B \subseteq Y$.

Then $f \left(f^{-1}(B) \right)$ $\subset B$

My proof:

$$f(x) \in f(f^{-1}[B])  \ \iff x \in f^{-1}[B] \iff f(x) \in B$$
  This proves that the two sets are equal. However, reading from other sources, one requires the function to be surjective in order to show that they are indeed equal, which I haven’t used in this case.

May someone clarify what I’m missing? I’m assuming that the last *if and only if* does not necessarily hold. Does the preimage exist only when the map is injective? Where does my proof fail?

Comment: You need *surjectivity* to show the sets are equal. In general, you need injectivity to show $f^{-1}\left(f(E)\right)=E$ where $E\subset X$, and surjectivity to show $f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)=B$ where $B\subset Y$.

Comment: Try writing the proof with all details and not take any shortcuts. For example, if $X=\{1\}$, $Y=B=\{1,2\}$ and $f:X\to Y$ is given by $f(1)=1$, then $f(f^{-1}(B))=\{1\}\neq B$, so the sets are not equal. Why doesn't your proof apply in this case?

Comment: What about elements of $B$ which are not image of anyone in $X$?

Comment: @Luiz Cordeiro, I see. My proof does in fact show that it is a subset. However just because $f(x)$ is in B does not mean B is a subset...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $~y~$ in $~f~f^{-1}(B)$ then $~\exists~\quad x~$ in $~f^{-1}(B)~$ with $~y = f(x)~$.  As $~f(x)~\in B\quad,\qquad y \in B$.